# Tiles + Velocity в Spring MVC

Tags: spring, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли стандартный способ использовать в проекте Spring MVC и Tiles и Velocity. Сходу нашел только [этот](http://anydoby.com/velocity/) загнувшийся проект и [этот](https://github.com/pete911/openhouse-web), видимо наследник первого. Не хотелось бы изобретать велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Использовал только Tiles. Способ интеграции c Tiles и Velocity довольно хорошо расписан в доках Spring . Интеграция с Tiles :

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Отдельно Tiles легко прикручивается. К Spring вообще легко прикручивается все, что не касается совместного использования нескольких UrlBasedViewResolver.